# could not read json data using jquery with for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I have a data object and inside that I have data object with json data inside. Here is how is looks like. the name of the file is `data.js`

```
var data = 
[
{
    title: 'this is title one',
    commit: 'this is commit'
},
{
    title: 'this is title two',
    commit: 'this is commit'
},
{
    title: 'this is title three',
    commit: 'this is commit'
},
{
    title: 'this is title four',
    commit: 'this is commit'
},
{
    title: 'this is title five',
    commit: 'this is commit'
},
{
    title: 'this is title six',
    commit: 'this is commit'
},
{
    title: 'this is title seven',
    commit: 'this is commit'
}
]
```

here is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                $(container).load(view, function () {
                    console.log(data[i].title);
                    li.append('<img src="../images/profile.png" alt="Profile photo" />');
                    li.append('<span class="commit">' + data[i].title + '</span>');
                    li.append('<p><a href="#" class="comment">' + data.commit + '</a></p>');
                    li.append('<section class="clear"></section>');
                    $('#home ul').append(li);
                });
            }
```

Now I am getting this error in my console

```
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

above error is on this line

```
li.append('<span class="commit">' + data[i].title + '</span>');
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, data.js is not really json.

First switch from load() to getJSON()

```
$.getJSON(view, function(data) { })
```

next remove the line

```
var data =
```

just have the json contents. jQuery will assign JSON to argument data.

Answer (score 0):

Your json array contains errors.

You can validate your json here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Must be so:

```
{
"title": ["this is title one", "this is title two", "this is title three", "this is title four", "this is title five", "this is title six", "this is title seven" ]
,
"commit": [ "this is commit", "this is commit", "this is commit", "this is commit", "this is commit", "this is commit", "this is commit" ]
}
```